# Replace value in csv with text and write it to file and center paragraph

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, replace

Note: Original code changed to reflect suggestions. Keeping the original post mostly intact for newbies, like me, to reference.

I have a csv file which can contain from zero up to all 4 of these values.

```
COLOUR,Code1,Code2  
Red,1,A  
White,3,D  
Blue,1,C  
Orange,2,D
```

I have a test file (test_test.txt) that has the following in it:

```
"Colours have come to symbolize many things. "
```

Where I am struggling is not knowing how to replace values. I want to search through the colour file and if a value is found, replace it with another value:

```
"Red is the colour of blood, rubies, and strawberries." replaces Red  
"WhitePages is the world's largest and most trusted source for business." replaces White  
"The term blue moon is used colloquially to mean a rare event." replaces Blue  
"Orange you glad I have no more colours?" replaces Orange
```

I want to write it to a text file in two formats (paragraph and list):

```
Red is the colour of blood, rubies, and strawberries, WhitePages is the world's largest and most trusted source for business, The term "blue moon" is used colloquially to mean a rare event, and Orange you glad I have no more colours?
```

**I would love to be able to center this in the text document:**

```
Red is the colour of blood, rubies, and strawberries  
WhitePages is the world's largest and most trusted source for business  
The term "blue moon" is used colloquially to mean a rare event  
Orange you glad I have no more colours?
```

Here is the revised code with suggestions incorporated. Any idea as to how to center last 4 sentences anyone?

```
import csv

with open('C:/Test/test_text.txt', 'a') as f:
    with open('C:/Test/colour.csv', 'rb') as test:
        colour_dict = {
            'Red':    "Red is the colour of blood, rubies, and strawberries",
            'White':  "WhitePages is the world's largest and most trusted source for business",
            'Blue':   "The term blue moon is used colloquially to mean a rare event",
            'Orange': "Orange you glad I have no more colours?"
        }
        reader = csv.DictReader(test)
        colour_list = tuple([colour_dict[row["COLOUR"]] for row in reader])

        # Wtite out comma separated list.

        if len(colour_list) == 0:
            colourGroup =  exit
        elif len(colour_list) == 1:
            colourGroup =  '%s' % colour_list #

        elif len(colour_list) == 2:
            colourGroup =  '%s and %s' % colour_list

        else:
            colourGroup = ('%s, ' * (len(colour_list)-1) + 'and %s') % tuple(colour_list)
        f.write(colourGroup)

        # Write  out list as separate lines.
        f.write ('\n\ncolour can influence our emotions, our actions and how we respond to various people, things and ideas. Much has been studied and written about colour and its impact on our daily lives.\n\nMany people believe that colours are powers, and that bright colours are especially powerful. Here are some of the meanings of colours and the energies contained in their corresponding stones.')
        f.write('\n\n' + ('\n'.join(colour_list)))
```

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which is "the colour file"? Where does the replacement take place? You have a csv file, but what else? Where does the output go?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I revised above code to reflect newest suggestion and added code to write variables to a text file. It all works except centering last bit.

Comment: It's not related to the question, but I thought I should mention that your `close` lines at the end of the code are unnecessary. They don't actually do anything (since you're missing the `()` for a function call), but if they did, it would duplicate the logic of the `with` statements, which will close your files automatically.

Comment: Good to know. Will revise.

Comment: If your only remaining issue is centering your text, you should look at [the string formatting documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). The `^` character says that you want a value centered within a given width. If you want your file to be 80 characters wide, you could use: `format(mystring, "^80")`

Comment: @Blckknght   I've been messing with it for awhile and am not getting it to work. Can you give me an example? I'm not even clear where in the script or what line of code I am supposed to put this modifier. Sorry if I seem impatient. Son is lurking around behind me waiting to get on the computer.

Comment: @user12059 I think you could put it in a generator expression in the `join` call in your last line. Something like: `"\n".join(format(line, "^80") for line in colour_list)` (or replace 80 with the width you want to center in).

Comment: @Blckknght open parenthesis was missing so I added it ('\n'.join(format(line, "^80") for line in colour_list)) but still got an invalid syntax error. At least I have a better idea of where to place the code when I figure out the syntax. Off to reread your link. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Had a stupid moment. Forgot to save script before running. Works fine. Final line reads like this. f.write ('\n\n' + ('\n'.join(format(line, "^80") for line in colour_list)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to translate your colors into the desired replacements:

```
colour_dict = {
    'Red':    "Red is the colour of blood, rubies, and strawberries",
    'White':  "WhitePages is the world's largest and most trusted source for business",
    'Blue':   "The term blue moon is used colloquially to mean a rare event",
    'Orange': "Orange you glad I have no more colours?"
}
colour_list = tuple([colour_dict[row["COLOUR"]] for row in reader])
```

Now, `colour_list` contains the colors replaced with their expression. You should handle exceptions in case the csv contains unexpected values.

Although not mentioned in your question, your goal seems to be to import the result into a Word document. If you want to do that, and have true centering of your text, I think the best way to go is to generate a Rich Text Format (RTF) file as opposed to a plain text file. That supports true centering and can be read by Word.

I uploaded [an example](http://temp-share.com/show/dPf3a6FtW), and maybe this [simple tutorial](http://www.pindari.com/rtf1.html) and [RTF specification](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm) can guide you. Or maybe using Word's XML format would work as well, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: Thanks. You suggestions worked great. I tweaked it a bit and added the code to write the results to a file the way I wanted it and replaced the revised code in post above. I just need to center the last bit and ultimately figure out how to import the whole thing into a word document. If I don't get an answer in the next day or two as to how to do these last things, I'll mark this as answered. Many thanks.

Comment: OK, you got some great suggestions already in the comments to you question. By the way, it looks like you have never casted a vote before. Check out [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for information about upvoting useful answers.

Comment: I added some suggestions using RTF to center your text. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doing this as an rtf is a great suggestion. Something new to make my head spin. At first glance, the links look great. The explanations seem to be written in simple terms so that newbies like me can grasp the concepts. Big thanks coming your way.